# Problem with normals, artifacts appear

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, normals

In the process of modeling the Anime head, I have artifacts, I suspect that the problem is in the normals, but after fixing the normals, the problem did not disappear, I am new to blender, please help. Here are the screenshots[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135077/discussion-on-question-by-awgo-problem-with-normals-artifacts-appear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bad artefact comes from these single edges you've extruded:

[image]

It comes from the split normals, which determine the shading, but it's hard to guess why it happens, technically, that said you're not supposed to have single edges like that in a mesh, as soon as you'll delete them or create a face it will disappear:

[image]